# What does "bound method PythonBreakpoint._ActivateBreakpoint" mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, stackdriver

I am using python webapp2 (used in GAE).
I'm seeing this exception in Logging.

```
<bound method PythonBreakpoint._ActivateBreakpoint of <google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.python.python_breakpoint.PythonBreakpoint object at 0x2ab09434da10>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1272, in default_dispatcher
    self.handlers[handler] = handler = import_string(handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1850, in import_string
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/python/imphook2.py", line 222, in _ImportHookBySuffix
    _ProcessImportBySuffix(name, fromlist, globals)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/python/imphook2.py", line 179, in _ProcessImportBySuffix
    _InvokeImportCallbackBySuffix(_import_local.names)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/python/imphook2.py", line 452, in _InvokeImportCallbackBySuffix
    callback(module)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/python/python_breakpoint.py", line 317, in _ActivateBreakpoint
    self._RemoveImportHook()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/python/python_breakpoint.py", line 398, in _RemoveImportHook
    self._import_hook_cleanup()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/python/imphook2.py", line 109, in RemoveCallback
    callbacks.remove(callback)

KeyError: <bound method PythonBreakpoint._ActivateBreakpoint of <google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.python.python_breakpoint.PythonBreakpoint object at 0x2ab09434da10>>
```

Here is my code.

```
import webapp2
ROUTES = [
    webapp2.Route('/sample', handler='sample_package.SampleClass', methods=['POST']),
...
]

APPLICATION = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    ROUTES,
    config=config)
```

This exception does not occur every time.

What does this mean and how can I remove it?
Is it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling a function without ()?

`a = b.func()` or `a = b.func`?

You might be returning the reference to the function instead of the output of the function if you don't include the parenthesis.

Comment: I don't calling a function without (). But I'm using webapp2 module.
I don't understand it was called without () inside webapp2.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code. It would help troubleshooting this.

Comment: I added it to the questionnaire.

Comment: The callstack says that an exception occurred in webapp2 library.
And there is no my code in callstack.
I think my code has not been called yet.
So I don't understand where my code is affecting. 
But in callstack
    File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/d22767677e9aa897/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1272, in default_dispatcher
I do not know if there is a relationship.
I wrote my code of routing.

Comment: Can you do a debug to see what line generates the error?

Comment: I put a log in my hander. But my log is not displayed...I cant see where my code is problem.I think it is webapp2 problem.

Comment: This looks like an issue with Stackdriver Debugger. Can you report the issue [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-python/issues) so that the Engineering Team can look into it?